# Credit load for Grad courses vs Undergraduate courses for professors

Tags: masters

As a professor I was wondering what others have experienced at the College/University regarding credit hours/compensation for teaching MA level vs BA level courses.  This is for a Psychology department...For example, a 3-credit BA course counts towards 3 credit hours of instruction. A 3-credit MA course may count at 3 credit hours or double (6-credit hours) depending on enrollment.  This policy is changing and I am wondering what policies may be in pace elsewhere for comparison.  In relation to this - how are professors compensated for mentoring MA thesis students?

Thanks in advance for any feedback that would be helpful while drafting our policy.

Comment: _A 3-credit MA course may count at 3 credit hours or double (6-credit hours) depending on enrollment._ - Where/what field is this?  I don't think I've heard of getting double credit for teaching grad classes before.

Comment: I think compensation for supervising students should be a sepetate question. You are also going to want to specify broad field (humanities, social sciences, STEM).

Comment: Social science - psychology

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK my faculty requires, over one academic year, two undergrad-level half courses, and one graduate-level half course ("half course" = one term, academic year has three terms). BUT, if one of the undergrad half courses is dual-listed as a graduate level half course, this counts for BOTH one of the undergrad-level half courses and the graduate-level half course. So, in theory, a professor could teach only two half courses and have it count for the three required.

Comment: Thanks - is there an enrollment requirement? We have had a required enrollment for the course to be double. Admin is planning to increase enrollment required & limit # of grad courses one can receive the double credit load for per year. We are on a semester sched and a 4:4 teaching load - so for ex: I could teach 1 grad & 2 undergrad each semester to cover my 4 required each semester now.  But, in the future I would need to teach 1 grad & 2 UG say in fall and then 1 Grad & 3 UG in spring. I am trying to get as much info as possible as there seems to be no consistency among Universities.

Comment: I don't think so, since most of the courses offered in my faculty are required for the undergraduates to take; and as long as even one graduate student is taking the grad-level course, it would still be double-listed (since the graduate students would have slightly different requirements in terms of content/labs/projects). Some grad courses are offered during the summer term, so some Profs will teach 1 UG fall, 1 UG Spring, and their grad in the summer.